# How will I get mysqli last insert id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How will i get the last insert id in mysql following code?

All variable are set.

Insertion works!

```
$Restconnection = mysqli_connect("host","user","passwd","db ");
$query3 = mysqli_query($Rconnection, $strSQL3);
```

Comment: Paste your query code too!!

Comment: you have to google first then ask if not found the solution.

Comment: `$query3->insert_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
echo "Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
```

Comment: You've missed a ``"`` after the query and before the ``;``

Answer (score 2):

```
print mysqli_insert_id($Restconnection);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_insert_id($connection)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
$last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($Restconnection);
```